# How to substring a string in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, for-loop, substring

I have function that uses a 'for loop' to find a url. Because the 'for loop' is looping over the  DOM array for links, each link is placed at an array index.

The url will look like this: http://reporter.highschoolsports-555.masslive.com/news/article/4040274705063720904/title287393467/

I need to cut off the beginning of the url to look like this: highschoolsports-555.masslive.com/news/article/4040274705063720904/title287393467/

When I use substring to remove the beginning of the url, I get an error, "function substr does not exist"

Is there a way to serialize or convert the array index data into a string to that I can use substring to edit the url?

```
var grabLinkFromList;    
var grablink= function(){

    var links=document.links;
    for (var i=0;i<30;i++){
    console.log("index "+i+" Link "+links[i]); 
    if(i==23){
        grabLinkFromList=links[i];

        var substringURL=grabLinkFromList.substr(0,15);
        alert(substringURL);
        }
}
```

I've also used this version of substring too:

```
var grabLinkFromList;    
var grablink= function(){

    var links=document.links;
    for (var i=0;i<30;i++){
    console.log("index "+i+" Link "+links[i]); 
    if(i==23){
        grabLinkFromList=links[i];

        var substringURL=grabLinkFromList.substring(0,15);
        alert(substringURL);
        }
}
```

Comment: It’s an HTML element. If you want its `href` property, use its `href` property: `grabLinkFromList.href.substring(15)` (I changed it, by the way, to `15` — `0, 15` gets the part you seem to want to remove.)

Comment: Thanks, but this code works to print out all the links in the dom if you remove the lines with substirng.

Comment: That’s because they override `toString`. How about just trying it? (Also, your loop, if you do actually end up grabbing only one link, can be replaced with `links[23]`.)

Comment: You are absolutely right!